# Wordpress custom category field returns matching post categories

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

So, I have the following query to show posts on a page template.

```
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('category_name=specials&posts_per_page=2' . '&paged='.$paged);
```

Where is have ***category_name=specials*** I'd like ***specials*** to be a dynamic field informed/taken from a custom field ON the page... so the page might have a custom field 'category' and it's value I can type in to be specials for example. Therefore the page will show all posts with the category matching what I've typed in the customer field value... Is this possible?

Comment: So you are trying to replicate the already existing category pages/archive functionality with your own? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assign the value of the custom field to a variable and use it in the query as shown below:

```
$custom_field = //get custom field value

$wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('category_name='.$custom_field.'&posts_per_page=2' . '&paged='.$paged);
```

Comment: $custom_field = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'category', true);

$wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('category_name='.$custom_field.'&posts_per_page=2' . '&paged='.$paged);

Many thanks Neil, that's what I needed. Here is the custom field line I've used which works well!

Answer (score 1):

**How to get the category wise post by using below code?**

Add category id and taxonomy slug in argument

```
    <?php
$post_type = 'post';
$page_paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'type'          => $post_type,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged'          => $page_paged, 
    'caller_get_posts' => -1,
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'pad_counts'    => false,
    'hierarchical'  => 1,
    'hide_empty'    => 0,
    'tax_query'                => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your taxonomy slug',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 'your category id'
        )
    ),
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_title('<h2>', '</h2>', true);
    the_content();
endwhile; // end of the loop. 

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Neil for a quick answer

Here is the full working block of code.

On the page, add a custom field 'category' then make sure the value of this custom field matches post categories which will return these posts on the page.

```
<?php // Display blog posts with category filter from custom field
    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
    $custom_field = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'category', true);
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('category_name='.$custom_field.'&posts_per_page=2' . '&paged='.$paged);

    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('category_name=specials&posts_per_page=2' . '&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read more"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

    <nav id="nav-posts">
        <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></div>
        <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts &raquo;'); ?></div>
    </nav>

    <?php } else { ?>

    <nav id="nav-posts">
        <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></div>
    </nav>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```